# Simple Form Not Respecting Input HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

So I have the following line:

```
<%= f.input :birth_date, as: :date, label: "Date of Birth", html5: true, input_html: {min: Time.now.year - 100.year, max: Time.now} %>
```

Which is generating:

```
<input class="form-Field-control date required dr-FormField-control" aria-invalid="true" name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[birth_date]" id="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_birth_date" type="date">
```

Any thoughts as to that for which I had not accounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As min and max you have to pass a `Date` object.

`Date.today - 100.years`